# How to fix D "memory leaks"

Tags: memory-leaks, d

So I've been searching for a solution to this problem for some time. I've written a program to take data from two separate text files, parse it, and output to another text file and an ARFF file for analysis by Weka. The problem I'm running into is that the function I wrote to handle the data read and parsing operations doesn't de-allocate memory properly. Every successive call uses an additional 100MB or so and I need call this function over 60 times over the course of the function. Is there a way to force D to de-allocate memory, with respect to arrays, dynamic arrays, and associative arrays in particular?

An example of my problem:

```
struct Datum {
     string Foo;
     int Bar;
} 

Datum[] Collate() {
    Datum[] data;
    int[] userDataSet;
    int[string] secondarySet;
    string[] raw = splitLines(readText(readFile)).dup;

    foreach (r; raw) {
        userDataSet ~= parse(r);
        secondarySet[r.split(",").dup] = parseSomeOtherWay(r);
    }

    data = doSomeOtherCalculation(userDataSet, secondarySet);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: once you are done with parsing files, set the pointers to null

Comment: I am not surprised. Every call to Collate() will read the whole file, and split it into strings...

Comment: I see you don't declare the `data` variable anywhere before you return it. Is this scoped at the module level? Same goes for `readFile`. I can only assume these variables survive past the end of the function execution and are where memory is accumulating. Try passing 'readFile' into the function by value and see if that makes a difference, and try declaring `data` internal to the function.

Comment: @Raghuveer I'm not using pointers implicitly anywhere in my code. Do the pointers associated with the dynamic arrays I've been using need to be set to NULL explicitly?

Comment: @DejanLekic There are multiple files. This a simplified version of my actual function which would choose the appropriate files based on a passed string. The files themselves are not that large and the space required to store the data is acceptable if it could be reallocated

Comment: @Ryan data is declared in the first line of the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the strings in the returned data still pointing inside the original text file?

Array slicing operations in D do not make a copy of the data - instead, they just store a pointer and length. This also applies to `splitLines`, `split`, and possibly to `doSomeOtherCalculation`. This means that as long as a substring of the original file text exists anywhere in the program, the entire file's contents cannot be freed.

If the data you're returning is only a small fraction of the size of the text file you're reading, you can use `.dup` to make a copy of the string. This will prevent the small strings from pinning the entire file's contents in memory.

Comment: Thanks so much, instead of it eating up 1.8GB of memory and crashing, it uses a cool 500MB and stays there. I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the `Collate()` result is duplicated after the call, it's probable that it's not collected by the GC and thus resides in memory while it's not used anymore. If so then you can use a global container that you reset for each `Collate()`:

```
void Collate(out Datum[] data) {
    // data content is cleared because of 'out' param storage class
    // your processing to fill data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried this but the size of data has been observed to decrease as well as increase so that doesn't appear to be the problem unless it's a reference to something else.